# Как подключиться к WSDL, если он не имеет URL?

Tags: soap, wsdl

Есть 6 WSDL, скачанных с сайта, но, как я понял, они не имеют URL. Как получить доступ к этому веб-сайту через WSDL, если они скачаны локально?

Comment: В wsdl описаны типы данных и операции, которые сервис (веб-сайт) может принимать. По wsdl вы должны сгенерировать набор типов на используемом вами языке и далее использовать их для общения с сервисом. Естественно, у сервиса есть url.

Comment: Есть сайт на нем лежат wsdl Файлы я их скачал ,но как найти url по которому они лежат? Ведь для того ,чтобы на основе их мне что то сгенерировать wsdl должен иметь путь Например http://test/test?wsdl. Правильно же ?

Comment: Нет. Для их использования никакой url не нужен.

Comment: Дайте хоть какой нибудь пример .Как использовать эти локальные wsdl. Я находил только примеры с использованием wsdl имеющее URL адреса. А вот локальные т.е скаченные с сайта wsdl Нет!

Comment: Просто подавайте эти wsdl на вход утилите, которую используете для генерации кода. Это может быть как url в интернете, так и путь на диске. Попробовать это - одна минута. | Вы бы хоть написали, какую платформу используете: язык, утилита и пр. Например: c#, VisualStudio (именно для них я могу дать пример).

Comment: Я вообще под Objective C хочу запилить т.е под приложение. Для других платформ тоже подойдет в качестве примера. Скиньте что у вас есть буду оч признателен.

Comment: Пример: в составе Visual Studio есть утилита wsdl.exe. Просто вызываем её с параметрами: `wsdl http://example.org?wsdl` или `wsdl c:\data\wsdl`. Всё!

Comment: Спасибо добрый добрый человек сейчас буду пробовать.Если у кого есть еще какие нибудь варианты мануалы и прочее скидывайте буду благодарен

Comment: Друзья еще такой вопросик wsdl с URL тут все понятно как будет взаимодействовать ,когда мы будем отправлять запросы. А как будет работать локальный wsdl ? Что то не соображу

Comment: wsdl никак не работает. Это не код! Это метаинформация! По нему генерируется код и далее используется этот сгенерированный код. Всё, после этого файлы wsdl можно выкинуть.

Comment: Я вот сколько видео пересмотрел ,мануалов перечитал везде используют wsdl с URL ,а вот локальные ,скаченные никто . С чем связано ?

Comment: А зачем их скачивать? Ведь это разовая операция. Подключился к адресу, сгенерировал, отключился. Хотя, конечно, скачивание так и так происходит в этот момент. А главное, что вы зациклились на слове URL? Это всего лишь _адрес_, _путь_ к файлу wsdl. Это может быть интернет-адрес (`http://...`), это может быть путь в файловой системе (`c:\...`) - суть от этого не меняется.

Comment: Вы упорно не указываете, какое средство (IDE, утилита и т. п.) собираетсь использовать. Лишь Objective C упомянули. Я вот на платформе .NET использовал сервисы. Там просто кликаешь пару раз мышкой в Visual Studio и вводишь адрес wsdl. [Ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx). После чего сразу же можно использовать сгенерированный и добавленный в проект код. PS: да, почти везде пишут "URL", а не "path", но в [документации](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/7h3ystb6(v=vs.96).aspx) к утилите wsdl.exe прямо написано, что может быть как url, так и path.

Comment: Использовать я буду Xcode для Xcode нашёл средство наподобие wsdl.exe в Visual Studio. Да документацию уже глянул ,что можно использовать как локальный так и URL.спасибо за разъяснения теперь все понятно.

Comment: Спасибо вы единственный человек которых мне разъяснил и ответил на все глупые мои вопросы .Чего не скажешь по трём оставшимся форумам где я тоже разместил подобный пост .